Magento 2 Mass Action PDF open into new tab instead of current tab
I have a mass action tab named 'PDF Invoice' on my invoice grid, and I want the PDF to open in a new tab instead of the current tab when I click on it. How can I achieve this ?

Please add more details about the issue with screenshot and custom code if any.
